# Am having trouble finding the minimum value in a 2D array

Tags: java

This is my sample code, I am having trouble with finding the smallest variable. It always returns zero while finding the largest variable works fine.
I have used the same technique but don't know where I am going wrong.

Please help me.

```java
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        smallest = array[i][0];
        largest = array[i][0];//set largest to 0 at each round
        mean = 0;
        
        System.out.print("Round " + (i + 1) + " Cards: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            if (in.hasNextInt()) {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                    array[i][j] = in.nextInt();
                    if (array[i][j] > 9) {
                        System.out.println("Must be between 1-9");
                        // Arrays.fill(array, null);
                        j = 0;
                        System.out.print("Round " + (i + 1) + " Cards: ");
                    }
                    // Largest value
                    if (array[i][j] >= largest) {
                        largest = array[i][j];  
                    }
                    
                    // Smallest value
                    //smallest = array[i][0];
                    if (array[i][j] < smallest) {
                        smallest = array[i][j];
                         
                    }
  
                    // total
                    mean += array[i][j];
                }
                break;
            } else {
                in.next();
            }

        }
        //mean calculation
        array[i][m] = largest;
        array[i][m + 1] = smallest;
        array[i][m + 2] = (int) mean / m;

    }
```

Comment: is my approach that complicated. please help me am new at this.

Comment: Where is your variable `m` used in the second for-loop?

Comment: M is used to print the values

Comment: m siginifies number of columns and n number of rows

Comment: What value do `m` and `n` have?

Comment: m is equal to 4 while n equals 8

Answer (score 0):

This would be a clean way to find the minimum and maximum value in a 2D array.
You can replace `i < array.length` with `m` and `i < array[i].length` with `n`, if I understood correctly what you were trying to say in the comments.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = new int[][]{{7, 8, 32439, 0}, {1, -32, 3, 5}};
        int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                if (array[i][j] < smallest) {
                    smallest = array[i][j];
                }
                if (array[i][j] > largest) {
                    largest = array[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(smallest);
        System.out.println(largest);
    }
```

> Output:
>
> -32
>
> 32439

Comment: the problem is with the if(array[i][j] < smallest) part of the code. It always returns zero compared to the similar largest expression.

Comment: My if block doesn't return anything, it assigns the variable `smallest`an int.
And a hint: You should read your input and then check for the smallest / largest value. Makes your code more readable and usually tasks are performed one after the other.

Comment: i have found the problem. I just moved the mean calculations to the inner for loop and everything works as it should. The problem where index values been referenced.